# Assigning Elements to array then printing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an issue where I need to put value from checkboxes into an array, then use toString() on the array and write the array contents to a div. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return false">
        <div id="inputs" class="alignAndWhiteText">
            <div style="margin-left:80px">
                <label>List music in the order you prefer</label>
                <hr style="margin-right:80px"/>
                <div id="selections">
                <input type="checkbox" id="popMusic">Pop Music<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="metalMusic">Metal Music<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="countryMusic">Country Music<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rapMusic">rap Music<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="electronicMusic">Electronic  Music<br>
                </div>
                <div id="userFeedback" style="color:white;text-align:center"><p></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

$(document).ready(function(){
var music = ["","","","",""];
$('#popMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#popMusic').val());
});
$('#metalMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#metalMusic').val());
});
$('#countryMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#countryMusic').val());
});
$('#rapMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#rapMusic').val());
});
$('#electronicMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#electronicMusic').val());
});
music.toString();

    for(i = 0;i < music.length; i++){
        $('#userFeedback').html(music); 
    }
```

});

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear with that. I just want to take the value of the checkboxes, when checked and add that value to the music array. Then display the contents of the music array in userFeedback div. Then I will try to make it so that when they deselect an item it will remove it from the array.

Comment: Okay, do you understand the JS you have written, and the flow of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you wanted? I have refactored code and leverage `each` of jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var music = [];
  $( ".musicSelection" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).change(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#userFeedback').append("<p>" + $(this).val() + "</p>");
         }
    });
         
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return false">
        <div id="inputs" class="alignAndWhiteText">
            <div style="margin-left:80px">
                <label>List music in the order you prefer</label>
                <hr style="margin-right:80px"/>
                <div id="selections">
                <input class="musicSelection" type="checkbox" id="popMusic" value="Pop Music">Pop Music<br>
                <input class="musicSelection" type="checkbox" id="metalMusic" value="Metal Music">Metal Music<br>
                <input class="musicSelection" type="checkbox" id="countryMusic" value="Country Music">Country Music<br>
                <input class="musicSelection" type="checkbox" id="rapMusic" value="rap Music">rap Music<br>
                <input class="musicSelection" type="checkbox" id="electronicMusic" value="Electronic  Music">Electronic  Music<br>
                </div>
                <div id="userFeedback" style="color:tomato;text-align:center"><p></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: That works very well, I should have thought to use a class selector instead of obtaining the id. Now I can build off this to get to remove items on checkbox deselect. Thank you for helping me and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If it helped you then feel free to mark it as Accepted Answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first off you forgot all your closing input tags.

Also you are after filling your array up with 5 empty indexes.

For each input box add a value attribute

Looping through the array to display the list and using .html() will overwrite the previous value so you need to use append.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var music = [];
  $('#popMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#popMusic').val());
    $('#userFeedback').append("Pop Music<br>");
  });
  $('#metalMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#metalMusic').val());
      $('#userFeedback').append("Metal Music<br>");
  });
  $('#countryMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#countryMusic').val());
  $('#userFeedback').append("Country Music<br>");
  });
  $('#rapMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#rapMusic').val());
 $('#userFeedback').append("Rap Music<br>");
  });
  $('#electronicMusic').click(function(){
    music.push($('#electronicMusic').val());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var music = [];
      $('#popMusic').click(function(){
        music.push($('#popMusic').val());
        $('#userFeedback').append("Pop Music<br>");
      });
      $('#metalMusic').click(function(){
        music.push($('#metalMusic').val());
          $('#userFeedback').append("Metal Music<br>");
      });
      $('#countryMusic').click(function(){
        music.push($('#countryMusic').val());
  $('#userFeedback').append("Country Music<br>");
      });
      $('#rapMusic').click(function(){
        music.push($('#rapMusic').val());
  $('#userFeedback').append("Rap Music<br>");
      });
      $('#electronicMusic').click(function(){
        music.push($('#electronicMusic').val());
  $('#userFeedback').append("Electronic Music<br>");
      });
      music.toString();
    });


</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return false">
        <div id="inputs" class="alignAndWhiteText">
            <div style="margin-left:80px">
                <label>List music in the order you prefer</label>
                <hr style="margin-right:80px"/>
                <div id="selections">
                <input type="checkbox" id="popMusic" value="Pop Music">Pop Music</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="metalMusic" value="Metal Music">Metal Music</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="countryMusic" value="Country Music">Country Music</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rapMusic" value="Rap Music">rap Music</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="electronicMusic" value="Electronic Music">Electronic  Music</input><br>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
      <div id="userFeedback" style="text-align:center"><p></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with the following approach:

- Use the `value` attribute to store the value of that particular input
- Use the `name` attribute to "cluster" the music inputs. Now you can select these inputs by name.
- Use event delegation to set event callbacks. This means the callback will not be set to every input element, but only once on a parent element (in this case `#selections`), which is more efficient.

UPDATE: After clicking the input will be disabled to prevent an endless list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var result = [];

$('#selections').on('click', 'input[name="music"]', function () {
    var $input = $(this);

    // add to the order list
    result.push($input.val());

    // disable input
    $input.prop('disabled', true);

    // show result
    $('#userFeedback').html(result.join('<br>'));
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selections">
    <input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Pop Music">Pop Music <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Metal Music">Metal Music<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Country Music">Country Music<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Rap Music">Rap Music<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Electronic  usic">Electronic Music<br>
</div>
<div id="userFeedback" style="text-align:center"></div>
```